# Base64 string difference

Tags: c++, base64

I'm sending from server to clients base64 strings with decoded coordinates of some objects. There are ~20 objects with x;y pair, 2 bytes per integer. This coords changes with time but some of them saves same values for about 2-3 sending calls.

Any ways to calculate the difference and send it instead of full base64 each time? The network traffic is very important here.

Here is the example of 2 strings made with 100ms pause:

```
AFg7IP+SAAJg/ana/zAA52BJO/D/9wAxIFkAIABIABQBSADtAFEAMGlLctX/
AFo7IP+SAAJgAKnb/0EA6GBJO/D//wA0IFkAIABIABQBSADtAEoAYmlLctX/
```

Comment: Why are you sending them as base64 anyway? Also: why don't you first send for example a boolean, that says if the values have changed or not, so you can omit unchanged values?

Comment: make your code smarter and only send changed values by default. If the client wants "all" values, let it request them.

Comment: I'm assuming that if bandwidth is at a premium, the cost of an extra request / response pair would swamp any savings from smaller responses. Also, there was no mention of bidirectional communication. Maybe this is a push model only.  Please clarify these points by editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pack the data efficiently in bytes, then encode if necessary. As @twall says, you should try hard to eliminate the base 64 because it expands the size of the data by 33% at least. Here is one way to pack it, if there are exactly 20 x,y pairs:

Bytes 1-3: bitset. Each bit represents an x,y pair. If set, there is an updated value for that pair in this message. Last 4 bits of 3rd byte unused.

Bytes 5&6 x coord of first point
Bytes 7&8 y coord of first point

... up to 19 more points

Max of 83 bytes, min of 3 bytes (no coords updated)

Comment: If the coordinates that do change only change a small amount you could get real fancy. In the bitset, reserve two bits for each x, y pair. Interpret the values as follows: 0 - no update, 1 - double byte new position, 2 - single byte positive offset from previous position, 3 - single byte negative offset from previous position